# Google Analytics with a b2b site - tracking sub sections

Tags: google-analytics

I've implemented GA on our b2b site. It's strictly internal but we'd like to track behaviors of users to see if some of the sections on the site are relevant.  So, it's working, but say you have

www.blahblah.com and you want to also track

www.blahblah.com/edit 
www.blahblah.com/askquestion

Do you set up a filter for this? I did try it and not sure if it's working quite yet. Any info/advice would be greatly appreciated. I am brand new to GA.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what you are asking.

If you want to know about metrics for the individual pages you'd go to to the Aquisition->Page Content reports. Overview will give you, well, an overview (you can use the filter box to look at the metrics for any specific Url), Content Drilldown will display a view structured by url hierarchy.

If you're after user behaviour you can create segments. If you want to know if somebody vistited the homepage and, after that, the /edit page you'd got to advanced segments (the arrow above the "Explorer" Tab in most views, click "create new segment", choose "sequence" from the advanced tab, choose page as dimension and "/" to filter for as step one,  "/edit" as filter value for page two, enter a name for the segment and click save. Now you'll get all reports only for visitors who have visited those two pages, starting with the homepage.

There are a number of predefined segments, you should try them to see what they can do. You need a pretty good understanding of metrics and dimensions in GA to get the full value from  segments, but the simple stuff (e.g. analyze differences between marketing channels) is already pretty useful.

So, for page performance seek out reports with page metrics and use filters. To analyze user behavior use segments which apply to most of the GA reports.

Hope that helps, if not you might to explain more specifically what you want to see in your reports.

Comment: THanks, I might not have been that clear. Sorry about that. I really just want to say how many times a page was visited in order to determine if we want to keep the sections of the site there.
So report on how many times /edit was visited, /store was visited etc. This has to do with adding filters I believe, but I wanted to be sure.\

Answer (score 0):

You can create separate custom report for individual sections and drilldown by almost all the GA provided dimensions. please reffer the sampel provided.

Please access [this URL](https://www.google.com/analytics/web/template?uid=e8g0pDSZTwigYJAV5QXMGw) in your browser as this is a predefined custom report which does the same thing you want. This will get saved under custom reports. You need to edit the custom report and give your own path/section insted of "/services/" under filters section

Comment: Thanks! I will give these both a shot.